# Windows command for image compression returns Invalid Parameter Error

Tags: windows, image, command-line, cmd, compression

I am trying to run the below command to compress file size of images on Windows system and it returns error message:

> Invalid Parameter 70

```
for %f IN (*.png) DO convert -quality 70 "%f" "%f"
```

I tried searching in world wide web for a solution, but couldn't find anything.

Is the syntax of the command wrong?

OR

Does this not work at all?

What am I missing here?

Comment: If PNG files are already compressed how come there are tools that compress them further and reduce the file size? And what is the syntax for "compact"?

Comment: If you have installed ImageMagick v7 or higher, you can use `magick` in place of `convert` to avoid a clash with Windows' `convert`.

Comment: If you wish to manipulate images and change their compression/quality/format/size, you almost certainly are looking for `ImageMagick` and the command you show (`convert -quality....`) is an ImageMagick command. If you have not installed `ImageMagick`, that is your problem and you should install it. If you have installed it, use `magick` instead of `convert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the full path to your `convert` command (ex: if you installed `convert.exe` to `C:\myprogs` provide `C:\myprogs\convert.exe` in your `for` loop) or DOS will use the built-in `convert` command , which is completely different (NTFS/FAT volume conversion)

On my machine (I haven't installed any `convert` programs):

```
C:\Users\xxxx>where convert
C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe
```

The built-in windows commands always come first in the PATH.

Slightly off-topic to explain a similar problem: When people try to call MSYS `find` or `sort` or generic named commands like that within the Windows command line. Other commands like `sed` or `grep` work fine because they don't exist in MS-DOS, but Windows `find` or `sort` exist and come first, unless ran from MSYS2 shell (not to mention: the user's script miserably fail as the commands meaning & syntax are different)

As seen in the other comments, I suppose you're mixing up with `compact` command.
`compact` command is a compression program, very unlikely to efficiently pack your images. You really need the ImageMagik package. Irfanview is not a command-line tool but has a nice batch mode which works well.

Comment: Well, this is not related to imagemagic. I checked imagemagic and it is working fine, but I found this command by googling DOS command for image compression (I don't have the link right now!) so I thought this was an internal DOS command. Is it not?

Comment: Editing the answer now.

Comment: So the built-in convert command works only for NTFS/FAT volume conversion and nothing else?

Comment: would be surprising if it could convert disk partitions AND images in the same command right?

Comment: I think I'll accept this answer along with Mark Stechell's comment above! I guess I was using the command wrong. I guess it's related to ImageMagick only...